How to measure a curve length from start to a specific point
I'm working on a complicated node tree that involves instances on curve points. I would need to create a node group that takes in position vector of a specific point or its index, either one is fine, and outputs curve length or factor in that specific point. Is this even possible? And if so how would I do it? Also, the points change position on the curve over time.

Use "Spline Parameter" node, "Length" output:

To read a specific index (not index of currently evaluated point) of current geometry, use "Evaluate at Index" node:

To read a specific index from another geometry, "Sample Index":

